# Updating a child component in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to update a child component in Angular 5, and cannot get it working.

My home component gets data via a service.

It has a function called getTopicToFilter which is updated by another component. This works fine and gives me the `TopicId` via an `@Output EventEmitter`.

My problem though is that articles aren't updating in a child component

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    loading = true;

    topics: Observable<Topic[]>;
    posts: Observable<Post[]>;

    public constructor(
        private blogService: BlogService
    ) { }


    ngOnInit() {
        this.posts = this.blogService.getPostsByTopic().share()
        // Note that the forkJoin gets other, unrelated data that I have removed from the question
        Observable.forkJoin([
            this.posts
        ]).subscribe(
            response => { },
            error => {
                console.log('An error occurred:', error);
            },
            () => {
                this.loading = false;
            });
    }

    getTopicToFilter(topicId) {
        // I've confirmed I get the right data back from my service based on the topicId
        this.posts = this.blogService.getPostsByTopic(topicId)
    }

}
```

**Html for HomeComponent:**

```
<app-posts [posts]="posts | async"></app-posts>
```

And finally my child PostsComponent;

```
export class PostsComponent{
    @Input() posts: Post[];

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        // only run when property "data" changed
        if (changes['posts']) {
            //  This is always outputting my original insights, not the filtered list
            console.log(this.posts)
        }
    }
}
```

Update - this is my BlogService

```
public getPostsByTopic(topicId = ""): Observable<Post[]> {
   return this.http.get<Post[]>(this.baseUrl + '/getPostsByTopic?TopicId=${topicId}', { headers });
}
```

Comment: Try by making `posts` property in `PostsComponent` public.

Comment: Please put the HTML dom code used. Seems posts are not updated correctly. Most often the arrays of posts used with ngFor can be easily updated by even a simple push.

Comment: Which HTML @gary? The html on the PostsComponent isn't really relevant as I'm trying to log in the console in the component

Comment: Does `BlogService` return a different array reference on each update? To be sure that you have a new one, try this: `getTopicToFilter(topicId) { this.posts = []; this.posts.push(...this.blogService.getPostsByTopic(topicId)); }`.

Comment: I've updated my question.  The line this.posts = [] gives the following error:  'Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Post[]>'.

Comment: So, `console.log(this.posts)` is executed in `ngOnChanges` after the changes, but showing the same values, or the statement is not reached at all?

Comment: Executed and showing the original value

Comment: Where is the html where posts are replicated? Just do a push or async on the *ngFor array object and it should work fine.

Comment: @RobbieMills here is the plunkr. Pls try playing with it. https://plnkr.co/edit/rQ2WLJtC2ksl9uwQX04L?p=preview

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Here is [a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6yfrpo), very similar to your case, and which may help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
export class PostsComponent implements OnChanges {
@Input() posts: Post[];

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
     for (let propName in changes) {
    // only run when property "data" changed
    if (propName === 'posts') {
         //  this line will update posts values 
         this.posts = changes[propName].currentValue

        console.log(this.posts) 
    }
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
export class PostComponent
```

to

```
export class PostComponent implements OnChanges
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use *ngIf on the child component,
for example

`<child-component [posts]="data | async" *ngIf="dataIsReady" ></child-component>`

In your parent component when you have to update the data

```
this.dataIsReady = false;
this.postService.getData().subscribe(
   (result: any) => {
     this.data = result;
     this.dataIsReady = true;
   }
);
```

*ngIf force the child component to reRender.
I hope you'll find this usefull